# Whitelist a login and IP Address in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am wondering if there's a way to whitelist a SQL Server login for a particular IP address. More specifically I want to achieve the following:

1. Any SQL Server logins, except login `SomeLogin`, can connect to the database server from any IP, and,
2. `SomeLogin` can connect to the database server only from a particular IP address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a trigger for this. Essentially, SQL triggers are fired when a specified event occurs and you can then use T-SQL to specify what to do when that even fires.

See this post [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84204/sql-server-how-to-create-user-with-access-only-from-specific-hostname-or-ip-ad) for one particular example of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am quite familiar with T-SQL triggers, and knew it could be achieved by that. I was wondering if that would be the best possible solution to achieve the above. If I had to deal only with IP address, I think a rule could be written at the DB server firewall, however, since I have to also consider SQL Server Login, I think triggers could be the best feasible solution here.